# Tell me the Feasibility of all features of ARCore and ARKit in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, arkit, arcore

I want to implement augmented reality in xamarin. There are very few example available.

**I want to put the point of interest (POI) on the camera view.**

***I am not able to find any sample in xamarin for ARCore and ARKit but in natively it's definitely possible. So can I assume that it is possible in xamarin also? I just want to check the feasibility of features.***

**is all features are wrapped in ARCore and ARKit library for Xamarin.Android and xamarin.ios?**

I found few samples in native android and IOS but I am confused that is it possible to implement the same feature in xamarin?

How do I know all features available in ARCore and ARKit?

Comment: iOS: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios11/arkit/
Android: https://blog.xamarin.com/augmented-reality-xamarin-android-arcore/

Comment: You mean to say that only these features are available right?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin API always 100 % covers all native APIs for both Android and iOS. You can be sure both ARKit and ARCore are fully supported. Although the approach might be a bit different sometimes (because the languages are different and Xamarin usually modifies the APIs to match more closely with the C# conventions), you can definitely rely on the fact that everything you can do native, you can do in Xamarin as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply but https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.ARCore/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.ARKit/ I found that both are having very less functionality, plugins are itself in progress and also downloads are very low.

Comment: The ARKit package is not any official one. Because ARKit is stable, it is a fully supported part of the Xamarin.iOS API and requires no additional NuGet package (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/ARKit/). ARCore is in prerelease still, but Xamarin will keep updating it along with the native version. When it is released as stable, it will be fully available in Xamarin as well, as a native API.

Comment: We can implement the whole feature in native android through ARCore or any third party augmented reality plugin and make "jar" file, convert that jar file into dll using https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/ that "dll" helps us to implement our requirement. Can you please tell me this approach is correct or not? Are you sure plot point of interest on camera view is available in the current ARKit plugin for xamarin.IOS?https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4.ARKit/

Comment: Hi, yes, you can absolutely do that. Regarding ARKit - as I mentioned, ARKit is part of the Xamarin.iOS API so there is no need to install any plugin.

Comment: @RutulMehta If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.